# iterating over named tuples in a list

Tags: function, python-3.x, tuples

Am trying to retrieve values from a namedtuple in a list. It takes one argument, a namedtuple or a list of namedtuples, and returns the value in the price field. Here is my code:

```
def price(rlist):
    for item in rlist:
        return item.price

RC = [
Restaurant("Thai Dishes", "Thai", "334-4433", "Mee Krob", 12.50),
Restaurant("Nobu", "Japanese", "335-4433", "Natto Temaki", 5.50)]

print(price(RC))
```

It should print 12.50 and 5.50..but it only prints 12.50. How can I improve or correct the iteration?

```
Book = namedtuple('Book', 'title author year price')

favorite = Book('Adventures of Sherlock Holmes', 'Arthur Conan Doyle', 1892, 21.50)
```

and then when I do:

```
 price(favorite)
```

It gives me an error:

```
for item in rlist:
TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable
```

Comment: I think you mean def price(rlist) rather than def price(list)

Comment: yes..sorry I corrected it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps use

```
def price(rlist):
    return [item.price for item in rlist]
```

to return what you seem to want

Comment: You should just use restaurant.price for individual restaurants and a list comprehension like John wrote for lists of restaurants.

Comment: @LeonSurrao I'm not sure what you mean by "take Restaurant as a parameter". The function I gave will return a list of prices for any list of named tuples which include a "price" field -- including the book example. The problem there was that you were applying it to a single item rather than a list.

Comment: @rikkigibson, is there a way get the result by using one function if I put an individual restaurant or a list?

Comment: @JohnColeman, is there a way to get the same result regardless of the parameter being a list or a single item?

Comment: Consider a list containing one restaurant. If you're trying to display the prices in some kind of output then use ", ".join(restaurants)

Comment: "is there a way get the result by using one function if I put an individual restaurant or a list?" Yes, but don't do that, especially since `favorite.price` gives it to you as easily as that. If a function takes a sequence, it should always take a sequence, otherwise lies madness.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) with [string.join](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.join) method.

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> Restaurant = namedtuple('Restaurant', 'name cuisine phone dish price')
>>> RC = [Restaurant("Thai Dishes", "Thai", "334-4433", "Mee Krob", 12.50), Restaurant("Nobu", "Japanese", "335-4433", "Natto Temaki", 5.50)]
>>> def price(a_tuple):
...     return ', '.join([str(rc.price) for rc in a_tuple])
... 
>>> price(RC)
'12.5, 5.5'
```

The method join return a string with elements of an iterable.

To solve the problem of only one namedtuple (and not a list of they) you can check if the argument has an attribute [_fields](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.somenamedtuple._fields) (namedtuples have this attribute)

```
>>> def price(a_tuple):
...     if hasattr(a_tuple, '_fields'):
...         return a_tuple.price
...     return ', '.join([str(rc.price) for rc in a_tuple])
... 
>>> price(RC)
'12.5, 5.5'
>>> price(RC[0])
12.5
```

This solution working with any iterable types (list, tuple, iterator, etc)